# kubectl deploy only one component from a yaml

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubectl

I have a yaml file which works if I deploy it using

```sh
kubectl apply -f myComponents.yaml
```

My question is, is there a way to deploy just one component from this YAML? For example, if my YAML has both deployment and service and I just want to deploy the service

I am looking for something like

```sh
kubectl apply -f myComponents.yaml Service
```

Answer (score 3):

No. ⛔

At least not yet. Currently, you can take advantage of tools like [kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/), to apply/create/delete what you'd like, but that's not necessarily the same thing.

Having said I've made [a feature request for kubectl](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/900) .

✌️

Answer (score 1):

No. You can use a command line tool to do this like yq though, depending on how fancy you want to be:

```
cat myComponents.yaml | yq 'some selector' | kubectl apply -f -
```